# Create an index hierarchy from two columns to map out customer retention

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I'm performing a churn analysis for work, and I have been trying to create a multi-index data frame based off an existing data frame.

I currently have a Dataframe structured something similar to this:

```
df.head(3)

CustomerID  Lifetime  Cohort  Monthly_Pay  Ltv_Rev  Sub   Pln_strt  pln Can
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
fgvghc        10     2010-5    14.99        150   2010-5  2010-5-3  2011-5-3
dhsdjk        2      2010-5    14.99        179   2010-5  2010-5-9  2010-7-8   
5uk0ez        3      2010-6    5.99         18    2010-6  2010-6-4  2010-8-2
```

I am trying to figure out the churn for each cohort over a 20 month period. The cohort column is the cohort itself, and the subscribe column marks the month for how many total users have retained. Example below:

```
                  Total_Users 
Cohort  Subscribe
-------------------------------
2010-5  2010-5        2
        2010-6        2
        2010-7        1
        ...
```

so far, I have been trying:

```
grouped = df.groupby(['Cohort', 'Subscribe'])
grouped.agg({'CustomerID': pd.Series.nunique})
```

But that doesn't work; it just prints the total users in each cohort, without really differentiating between the Cohort and Subscribe column:

```
                   Total_Users 
Cohort  Subscribe
-------------------------------
2010-5  2010-5        2
2010-6  2010-6        4
2010-7  2010-7        12
```

I also tried:

```
    grouped = df.groupby(['Cohort', 'Subscribe'])['CustomerID'].size()
```

### but that prints the above result but within a series.

Update: I didn't post my actual dataframe for the sake of space, but now I realize that I omitted possibly important information. I added the Plan start date, and the plan cancel date.

I think the problem with mapping retention per cohort stems from an incorrect way of utilizing the CustomerID, the total customer lifetime, and the start and cancel dates.

Anyone able to help a rookie out?
           ...
For reference, I have been using this as a guide.
http://www.gregreda.com/2015/08/23/cohort-analysis-with-python/

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to use `size()`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['fgvghc', 10, '2010-5', 14.99, 150, '2010-5'],
                   ['dhsdjk', 12, '2010-5', 14.99, 179, '2010-5'],
                   ['akdsfj', 12, '2010-5', 14.99, 179, '2010-6'],
                   ['5uk0ez', 3, '2010-6', 5.99, 17.97, '2010-6']],
                  columns=['Customer_ID', 'Lifetime', 'Cohort',
                           'Monthly_Payment', 'Lifetime_Rev', 'Subscribed'])

res = df.groupby(['Cohort', 'Subscribed'])['Customer_ID'].size()
```

Result:

```
Cohort  Subscribed
2010-5  2010-5        2
        2010-6        1
2010-6  2010-6        1
Name: Customer_ID, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for responding. I made the suggestions as recommended but it produced the same results but within a series. I updated the original dataframe to include data that I omitted originally.